# Javascript literal escaped in IE but not Firefox, Chrome or Safari

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, escaping

I have generated inline code that assigns values to a javascript array.  One of the elements of the array should be set to "c:\folder\somefilename".  The statement is huge so I omitted most for the sake of brevity:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">    
var StepsList = {"steps": [
    {
        "id": "RST4551509111516131001035411012110410849",
        "stepAudio": "",
        "screenImage": "IO1A.PNG",
        "demoNote": "",
         "controlRect": {
            "top": "297",
            "left": "256",
            "right": "277",
            "bottom": "318"
            },
        "valueText": "c:\uploadfile.txt",
        "label": "Presentation Server File"
    [snipped]
</SCRIPT>
```

The content of the valueText element, "c:\uploadfile.txt" is captured from user input prior to code generation. When this code is executed in Chrome, Firefox, IE5, IE6 or Safari, the literal is not parsed and simply assigned to the array correctly.  IE7,8 and 9 throw an error "Expected hexadecimal digit" seeing the "\u" as an escape sequence.

I don't want javascript parsing my literals for escape characters.  I have tried the old   and putting it in a CDATA tag.  Is there a work around for this problem?

TIA,
Eddie

Comment: Well, ``\`` is the escape character in JS strings, there is nothing you can do about it. If you want a literal backslash, you have to escape it.

Comment: So it appears the answer is to parse the user input during input in the managed code and save the escaped data, then escape the data again  during generation then escape the data a third time when the user re-enters the data.  Or - don't support IE8 or IE9.

C# lets you prepend an "@" before the literal to tell it not to escape the literal. i.e. @"c:\folder\file"  vs "c:\\folder\\file".

Answer (score 2):

If your string will contain a literal backslash, it must be escaped. For example:

```
{"valueText": "c:\\uploadfile.txt"}
```

If you're creating the JSON with a library on the server, it would automatically be escaped. That is, please don't generate JSON by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
"valueText" : "c:\\uploadfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z73t8ex7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) indicates that the proper way to handle this in JScript (IE) is to use two backslashes.

> Note:
>   If you want to use the literal text \u in a string, then use two backslashes - (\u) — one to escape the first backslash.